# Restrict the up and down key on datagridview

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a datagridview on form. When user clicks on a data on datagridview, program calculates something. But user also can select data by using up and down arrow key on keybord. I dont want this. Because i put my calculating codes in Datagridview_CellClick events. If i also put it in Datagridview_SelectionChanged event, program calculates it twice when user clicks on datagridview. I mean i want to protect user to navigate the datagridview by pressing up and down arrow key by keybord. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must your calculation happen when the user clicks within the DataGridView? If your calculation is based upon the data within the grid then you would be better off using the `CellValueChanged` or `CellValidateEvents` to trigger the calculation.

It wasn't 100% clear from your question whether you did or did not want the calculation to happen on the up and down keypress. The reason it is unclear is the the `CellClick` event does **not** occur on an up or down arrow keypress, so that should not be a problem.

If you want to calculate on these keypresses you could either use the `CellEnter` event or handler the `KeyPress` - the advantage of the keypress is that you can check there which key was actually pressed if needed.